# Different calls from the same JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

In a JSP page I use one form to get the entire DB and another form (and the related servlet request and the specific sort command). Once I sort a field, the form with the whole DB become empty, so the two Forms are not working one after another, as I expected.

For the moment I am not sure whether it's a HTML problem or something else, so I put just a second button to get a refresh. However, I assume there must be a smarter & simpler way using jQuery.

Thank you in advance!

```html
<table cellpadding="10">
  <form name="Refresh" action="AllPost">
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh " /> &brvbar;
  </form>
  <form name="F" action="SortedPost" id="formular" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sort: " />
    <select name="Titl">
      <c:forEach items="${AllPost}" var="p">
        <option> ${p.Item} </option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
  </form>
</table>

<table>
  <c:forEach items="${SortedPost}" var="p">
    <tr>
      <td>ID: ${p.id}</td>
      <td>bla bla : ${p.blabla}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>

<table>
  <c:forEach items="${AllPost}" var="p">
    <tr>
      <td>${p.id}</td>
      <td>bla bla : ${p.blabla}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format code in your questions so it's readable. I've edited it for you in this case.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Shortly: to have both tables full, but only 2nd form used. Thank you!